# How do I program my own setenv()?

Tags: c, environment-variables, setenv

My school wants me to implement the `setenv()` standard [c](/questions/tagged/c) library function's behavior.  I'm not allowed to use `setenv()` for this implementation. How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with setenv?

Comment: It's in stdlib, should work, no?

Comment: I can't use setenv my school forbit using it

Comment: My school wants I create the setenv function

Comment: @Myranova Maybe you should clarify your question to indicate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On many implementations of the C programming language and especially on POSIX, the environment is accessible from the `environ` global variable. You may need to declare it manually as it's not declared in any standard header file:

```
extern char **environ;
```

`environ` points to a `NULL` terminated array of pointers to `variable=value` strings. For example, if your environment has the variables `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, the entries in `environ` might be:

```
environ[0] = "foo=a";
environ[1] = "bar=b";
environ[2] = "baz=c";
environ[3] = NULL;
```

To alter the environment without using the `setenv()` or `putenv()` functions, check if the key you want to set already exists. If it does, overwrite the entry for that key. Else you need to copy the content of `environ` into a new array and add the new entry to its end. You can use `malloc()` or `calloc()` and `memcpy()` for this purpose. Since this is homework, I'm not going to supply further details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution

Comment: @FUZxxl I realized that this was the solution, but I also suspected that you would write it.

Comment: @Myranova This is the acceptable answer because it's correct. Whether you try it and it works or not, depends on your skills with `malloc()` and `memcpy()`. Not that you can end up corrupting the `environ` buffer.

Comment: @FUZxxl: adding a new string at the end will not always produce the expected behavior, the OP should first scan the strings to find a potential match for the environment variable whose value needs to be set and not copy this line into the new environment array.